# different behaviour ionic modal background opacity

Tags: ionic-framework

We have just upgraded from Ionic beta 14 to the Ionic 1.0.0 release. After the upgrade we have one issue left which I can't solve.

I have added 2 CodePens to show the problem, being:

`1.0.0-beta.14`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVxxzM

`1.0.0`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVjjYJ

```
<ion-modal-view style="width: 50%;">
```

If you look at the 1.0.0-beta.14 CodePen and open the modal by hitting the button top right and you make your browser view smaller than 680px you will see that the modal still has a dark background around it.

Do the same with the 1.0.0 CodePen en you will see the dark background color is gone. Any ideas howto fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {
    .active .modal-backdrop-bg {
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000;
    }
}
```